# Node.js - Get ID of href in app.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using an href to link the user to a route. My problem is that I need to send a parameter to the dashboard while clicking on the link. The easiest way to do this would be to get the id or name of the href in the app.js and send it to the dashboard.

Here is my code:

```
 //the href in the index.ejs
 <a href="/dashboard" id="ANDROID">ANDROID</a> 

 //in the app.js
 app.get('/dashboard', function(req, res) {
     var url = req.url;
     console.log("url: " + url);    //prints out url: /dashboard
     var id = req.url.id;
     console.log("id: " + id);      //prints out id: undefined
 });
```

How can I grap the id or name of the href?

Comment: It's hard to know what you are actually trying to achieve, but at a guess I'd say that it's because req.url only returns the url and doesn't have information on the link that it came from.

I'd consider argument passing, express facilitates this: http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#app.param

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to pass the parameter to the URL. The ID of the "a" element is only a DOM ID and it is not in any way connected to the URL the link leads to.

You could try something like this:

```
<a href="/dashboard?id=ANDROID" id="ANDROID">ANDROID</a>
```

Then in the code:

```
app.get('/dashboard', function(req, res) {
    var id = req.query.id;
    ...
});
```

Comment: Now I do get the Parameter. But the app.get('/dashboard',..) needs to be edited. At the moment it is throwing: 'Cannot GET /dashboard?id=ANDROID'. How does the link in app.get needs to be edited?

Comment: I am not sure where is the error from, I tried to emulate an express server in my own environment and I do not get such issue. Did you send back the response? I am thinking this might've been an old error and the requests you are sending are still pending. My script for reference: http://jsfiddle.net/ukaom13p/

Comment: now it is working, I forgot to include my exports method to render the view. Thank you very much!